# How to display Bootstrap cards inline dynamically

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

thanks in advance for the help. I am using Angular to pull in data and style it with Bootstrap.

Currently, the cards are showing on top of each other. But, how would one display the cards horizontally inline?

Here's my code:

```
 <div class="card-deck text-center">
        <div class="card box-shadow">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">{{ forecast.value.date | date: 'MMMM d, y'}}</h4>
        </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
            <li><img src="{{ forecast.value.hourly[0].weather_icons }}"></li>
            <li>Average Temprature: {{ forecast.value.avgtemp }}&deg;F</li>
            <li>Precipitation: {{ forecast.value.hourly[0].precip }}"</li>
            <li>Summary: {{ forecast.value.hourly[0].weather_descriptions }}</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here's how's it is showing:
[image]

Here's what I am looking for:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just define some `col-*` classes inside a row.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card-deck text-center row">
  <div class="card box-shadow col-sm">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">{{ forecast.value.date | date: 'MMMM d, y'}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
        <li><img src="{{ forecast.value.hourly[0].weather_icons }}"></li>
        <li>Average Temprature: {{ forecast.value.avgtemp }}&deg;F</li>
        <li>Precipitation: {{ forecast.value.hourly[0].precip }}"</li>
        <li>Summary: {{ forecast.value.hourly[0].weather_descriptions }}</li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card box-shadow col-sm">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">{{ forecast.value.date | date: 'MMMM d, y'}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
        <li><img src="{{ forecast.value.hourly[0].weather_icons }}"></li>
        <li>Average Temprature: {{ forecast.value.avgtemp }}&deg;F</li>
        <li>Precipitation: {{ forecast.value.hourly[0].precip }}"</li>
        <li>Summary: {{ forecast.value.hourly[0].weather_descriptions }}</li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So as I said the cards are dynamically generated. You have them hard-coded here. So even with the col it is not working.

Comment: @Devvvvv Can you provide more detail on how you are dynamically generating these by updating your post or by providing a working StackBlitz project that I can then use to better help you resolve your issue. Thanks. There is no `ngFor` of the liked referenced in your code snippet.